# Configuring WSO2 AS and BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am using BAM 2.2.0. I configured the service statistics toolbox inside the BAM server based on the documentation. And run the example program "service-stats"it is working fine. 
But when I configure BAM inside my AS server using service data publisher configuration, and test the BAM server.Connection was established. But when I click the dashboard in BAM it shows an empty page with some msg how to configure AS .

Currently inside the BAM available script I can see "service-stats-271". How can I visualize my AS service status in BAM. Both servers are running in two machines.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing "service-stats-271" is natural after installing the toolbox. But first you should see whether data has arrived to Cassandra from AS. For that you can login to Cassandra Explorer in BAM Management Console and see whether there is your column family existing in the EVENT_KS keyspace. If yes see whether there are any rows relevant to your events. If yes see whether the data has arrived to the H2 datbase during the execution of the Hive query.

If your data is not correctly published to Cassandra, please read [1] again. Sometimes you may not have done the following instruction mentioned there.

```
Go to <WSO2 Application Server home>/repository/conf/etc and open bam.xml file and enable ServiceDataPublishing as follows: 


<BamConfig>   
     <ServiceDataPublishing>enable</ServiceDataPublishing>
</BamConfig>
```

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/Setting+up+Service+Statistics+Data+Agent

Comment: Assume you mean the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700758/configuring-wso2-as-and-bam-new-error . I answered that question.