# Configuring WSO2 AS and BAM -new error

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I followed the same steps as mentioned in the WSO2 documentation for configuring BAM server and WSO2 AS. Both are in different computers. Still not able to solve the errors. Now I am getting new error when I click BAM EVENT_KS. My BAM server offset address is 0 by default. I changed my WSO2 AS offset to 2 in carbon.xml.

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher} -  Error while connection to event receiver
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Cannot borrow client for TCP,203.252.180.178:9443,TCP,203.252.180.178:9543
>     at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:58)
>
> and many more .....

Please help what will be the configuration problem with BAM. I tried all the latest 3 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [1] for configuration details. As I can see you have used ports 9443 and 9543 instead of 7611 or 7711 which are the correct Thrift server ports.
Use 7611 for unsecured port and 7711 for the secured port when no port offset is applied in BAM.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS501/Collecting+Data+Statistics+of+Services